# jQuery How to capture and send id input field into virtual keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I work with virtual keyboard, and i stuck, so problem is, in my view i have few input field for which i need put some data use virtual keyboard.

So when i tap in to input field, i capture id, and send for keybord file with setup, but i received error.

Code:

```js
var idElement;
let Keyboard = window.SimpleKeyboard.default;

let keyboard = new Keyboard({
    onChange: input => onChange(input),
    onKeyPress: button => onKeyPress(button)
});
document.querySelector("#" + idElement).addEventListener("input", event => {
    console.log("#" + idElement);
    keyboard.setInput(event.target.value);
});

console.log(keyboard);

function onChange(input) {
    document.querySelector("#" + idElement).value = input;
    //console.log("Input changed", input);
}

function onKeyPress(button) {
    console.log("Button pressed", button);

    console.log("#" + idElement);
    if (button === "{shift}" || button === "{lock}") handleShift();
}

function handleShift() {
    let currentLayout = keyboard.options.layoutName;
    let shiftToggle = currentLayout === "default" ? "shift" : "default";

    keyboard.setOptions({
        layoutName: shiftToggle
    });
}


var modal = $('.modal');
$('.show-modal').click(function () {
    modal.fadeIn();
});

$('.close-modal').click(function () {
    modal.fadeOut();
});

$(function () {
    $('.dataInput').click(function () {
        idElement = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

```css
.simple-keyboard {
    max-width: 850px;
}

.modal {
    background-color: #dbd9d9;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.close-modal {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-keyboard@latest/build/css/index.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <input type="text" class="dataInput" id="poBarCode" placeholder="Enter number">
    <input type="text" class="dataInput" id="operationBar" id="opBarcode" placeholder="Enter number">
    <input type="text" class="numbQuan dataInput" id="quantityParts" placeholder="Enter number">
    <input type="text" class="dataInput" id="nestNumber" placeholder="Enter number">
    <div class="modal">
    <a class="close-modal" href="#">X</a>
      <div class="simple-keyboard"></div>
     </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-keyboard@latest/build/index.min.js"></script>
```

So as u can see from my example i fetch input field ID, and send in to scripti which call keyboard.

And i recived error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`idElement` is `undefined` when you're calling `document.querySelector("#" + idElement)...`, which makes the `querySelector` call return `null`, which you're then trying to call `addEventListener` on.

Comment: How i can fix it?

Comment: By setting the value of `idElement` before trying to query for that element and add a listener to it.

Comment: Can you provide some example?